# c# listbox autoscroll not working

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listbox

I have made a chat application in c#. Messages will be stored into a SQL server database and messages will be also read out of the database to the client application. As controls there is a ListBox item that contains messages read from the database, and a textbox to send messages (insert them into the database to be read out later). To read the messages from the database I'm using a sqlDataReader object that reads the string of the message in the database. I've added a timer to the form and set its interval to 1000ms.

The timer function contains the next code:

```
lblUsername.Text = "Ingelogd als: " + User.username.ToString();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=Chat; Data Source=DESKTOP-9S5PJV3\SQLEXPRESS";
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from tblMessages where messageReceiver=" + "'" + User.username.ToString() + "'";

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();



        while (dr.Read())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(4) + " zegt: " + dr.GetString(1));
            listBox1.Items.Add("");

        }
```

ListBox1.Items.Clear() clears all messages and after that reads them again. If I don't use Clear() the ListBox will contain all messages duplicated every second.

I've used the `listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;` for an auto scroll function but this doesn't work (I think because that the listbox needs to be cleared everytime). Is there a way to auto scroll the listbox anyway? At the moment it will not scroll down and the listbox will flash as hell...

Comment: You need to set `TopIndex` property to scrool down. Like this; `listbox.TopIndex = listbox.Items.Count - 1;`

Comment: This doesn't work. It works the same for me as the selectedindex. The problem is that I need to clear the items of the ListBox, so it scrolls to above when the items are cleared and it scrolls down again when the items are back.

Comment: Try, `Thread.Sleep(3000);` before `Clear();`

Comment: On a side note - PARAMETERISE THAT QUERY! lest ye leave oneself open to injection attacks!